# Crystal Report: Call stored procedure using sql expression

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

Apologies if this shouldn't be asked here, but I'm desperately wanted to know if it's possible to call a stored procedure from sql expression in Crystal Report.

Thank you so much!

Comment: what do u mean by SQL expression??

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function. Stored procedure does not return anything.